# Avoiding estate taxes on US ETF investments for non-US citizen

Tags: etf, vanguard, estate-planning

Typically I have been investing in Vanguard ETFs e.g. VXUS, VTI etc. via a US brokerage (Drivewealth). As I near the $60,000 limit for the estate tax exemption (non-US citizen, resident outside US, no Green Card; so I would be liable to 40% estate taxes) I've been trying to brainstorm solutions.

One way out seems to be to use non-US domiciled ETFs. Any comments if this is a good strategy?

Also, any equivalents to VXUS / VTI that would escape the US estate tax? If at all possible it's convenient if I can stick to my US brokerage account.

Comment: Which country do you live in? Have a look at Boglehead's [Nonresident alien's ETF domicile decision table](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Nonresident_alien%27s_ETF_domicile_decision_table).

Comment: Thanks. Resident of India. I believe no tax treaty exists that covers estate taxes.